# How to get context in uiautomator test case?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-uiautomator

I have my uiautomator test case:

```
public class clickTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {   

   public void myTest() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {   
       ...
       //Is it possible to get Context or Activity here?  

   }
}
```

I am wondering, is it possible to get `Context` or `Activity` instance in `UiAutomatorTestCase` ?

Or How to get `PackageManager` in `UiAutomatorTestCase` ?

Comment: You certainly cannot get access to the `Activity`, as it is running in a separate process. I am not aware that you can get a `Context`, either, let alone `PackageManager`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same, I post the question just to make sure :) , the reason why I want to access context is that I would like to use the PackageManager in my test. Let's see are their other people know more about it

Comment: Will you declare and instantiate the clickText?

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 this is the answer:

To get a Context for the target application being instrumented. [See details here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation#getTargetContext()):
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();`

To get the Context of the instrumentation's package. [See details here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation#getContext()):
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PackageManager by running the command directly from your uiautomator test case:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm uninstall com.example.MyApp");
```

However if you need access to context, Activity, etc. it may be best to use Android's InstrumentationTestRunner, look through the excellent Android documentation for more info.
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with UiAutomator 2.0 or later.

The original version of UiAutomator ran as a shell program (`adb shell uiautomator runtest ...`). Since it was not running as an Android application, it did not have access to the application Context object.

UiAutomator 2.0 is based on [Android Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#Instrumentation). Tests are compiled to APKs, and run in an application process (via `adb shell am instrument ...`). If your test extends [InstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html), you can use `getInstrumentation().getContext()` to obtain a Context.

See the [UiAutomator docs](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {

        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works -

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
```